# Choose an environment variable based on the branch name and store its value to another environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to send email notifications to specific user whose branch is currently checked out in the Jenkins build process. For accomplishing this, I have used naming conventions in the environment variables.

**E.g.**

1. `master_MAIL = abcd@gmail.com`
2. `ABC_MAIL = xyz@gmail.com`

Where `MASTER` and `ABC` are actual branch names.

`env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH` gives me with the current branch name being checked out.

Based on the current branch name, I have to pick the correct environment variable, and store its value (mail ID) to another environment variable.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        CURRENT_MAIL = "\$${env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}_MAIL"
        // Here I am trying to pick the specific mail id of the branch being
        // check out and store it to new environment variable named 
        // "CURRENT_MAIL".
        // But This gives only the value "$master_MAIL" but not the value
        // stored in master_MAIL environment variable.
    }

    stages {
    }

    post {
        always {
            mail (
            from: ""
            to: "$CURRENT_MAIL"
            // Here I have to use that environment variable to send email to
            // that specific user.
            subject: "")
        }
    }
```

The expected result is: `CURRENT_MAIL` environment variable should have the value contained in the `{Branchname}_MAIL` environment variable.

E.g. Consider I have these two environment variables set in my configuration:

```
master_MAIL = abc@gmail.com
ABC_MAIL = xyz@gmail.com
```

Then, if the current branch being checked out is `master` branch, then the environment variable `CURRENT_MAIL` should have the value `abc@gmail.com`.

Comment: When indenting your question's source code I've noticed there is a missing curly bracket closing the pipeline block. Is it also like that in your jenkins configuration, or is it just a copy & paste error to Stack Overlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the groovy `evaluate()` [helper method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) for dynamic evaluation of groovy expressions.

```
environment {
    CURRENT_MAIL = evaluate(env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH + '_MAIL')
    // OR using Groovy GStrings as
    // CURRENT_MAIL = evaluate("${env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}_MAIL")
}
```